# Positioning problems for a grid of boxes in a containing div

Tags: css, html-lists, haml

I'm trying to achieve this effect: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/wxdCD

I'm using SASS (.sass syntax) and haml, and while everything works with sass/haml in CodePen after I revise the code, it doesn't operate in the same way when I apply it to my app.  I would like the boxes to float in a grid within the containing div `#notecardContainer`

Unfortunately I just joined and don't have a reputation score high enough to post a picture, which is rather counter-productive.  But here's a link: [Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6910513/Screen%20shot%202013-09-13%20at%209.36.27%20AM.png)

Essentially, the boxes are appearing within the containing div `#notecardContainer`, but they are severely offset to the right by about 50% the width of the containing div `#drawer`  Also, they are stacking vertically, not horizontally, and they don't flex with change in the screen size.  I'm not sure why it works in CodePen but not in my code.

**SASS**: (NOTE: the indentation MAY not translate correctly to StackOverflow)

```
#drawer 
    width: 680px
    height: auto
    margin-left: auto
    margin-right: auto

#notecardContainer
    width: inherit

.ul.box
    position: relative
    z-index: 1
    overflow: hidden
    list-style: none
    li
        position: relative
        float: left
        width: 300px
        height: 150px
        padding: 0
        border: 1px solid #000
        margin: 0 30px 30px 0
        background: #fff
        &:before,
        &:after
            content: ''
            z-index: -1
            position: absolute
        &:after
            left: auto
            right: 10px
```

**HAML**:

```
    #notecardContainer
      %ul.box
         %li
         %li
         %li
```

Comment: Can you post a link to your page? A screenshot doesn't really say what is going on with your code.

Comment: I'm working on it locally on a Rails app yet. Any chance you can detect a problem through the code alone?

Comment: No way, everything looks ok in the code, so, i recommend you to use some html debugger that will help you, if you are using Mozilla, you can install Firebug, Google Chrome has its own built-in debugger. Using this tools you can make css and html changes on the fly and see the changes immediately.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes Kstro21 I did.  I just tweaked it in Chrome using developer tools until I discovered what I needed to do.  Thanks so much for that useful suggestion!